# Send another email after order confirmation email

Tags: magento2, order-email

Can someone advise what is the best approach or give me some points on how can I send another order confirmation email (Second Email is configured in Marketing->Email templates in Admin panel).  Magento automatically sends one confirmation email after the order is successfully placed.  My requirement is to send another one after this confirmation email is sent.  Would an observer be the right choice or a cron job is good? Kindly advise me with any examples if possible

Edit:  I need to wait like for a minute or two before the second email is sent

Answer (score 0):

Observer, if it's on the proper event, it could indeed work, the best approach might be to make an after plugin may be.
But defitively not a cron job, unless you want to handle it dayly and not instantly

Comment: Thank you, I missed to add that I need to wait for like a minute or more to send this second email..that's why I couldnt finalize with observer

Comment: In that case you need to run a cron each X minutes checking all the order made in the last X minute and seding the mails for these order. Observer and plugin would be to treat it directly